# ajaxify-html5.js reload only part of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I found the following script online that makes your website load content with AJAX.

Everything works fine, but it also reload my music player that has to stay when clicking a link.

```
// Ajaxify
// v1.0.1 - 30 September, 2012
// https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify
(function(window,undefined){

// Prepare our Variables
var
    History = window.History,
    $ = window.jQuery,
    document = window.document;

// Check to see if History.js is enabled for our Browser
if ( !History.enabled ) {
    return false;
}

// Wait for Document
$(function(){
    // Prepare Variables
    var
        /* Application Specific Variables */
        contentSelector = '#content,article:first,.article:first,.post:first',
        $content = $(contentSelector).filter(':first'),
        contentNode = $content.get(0),
        $menu = $('#menu,#nav,nav:first,.nav:first').filter(':first'),
        activeClass = 'active selected current youarehere',
        activeSelector = '.active,.selected,.current,.youarehere',
        menuChildrenSelector = '> li,> ul > li',
        completedEventName = 'statechangecomplete',
        /* Application Generic Variables */
        $window = $(window),
        $body = $(document.body),
        rootUrl = History.getRootUrl(),
        scrollOptions = {
            duration: 800,
            easing:'swing'
        };

    // Ensure Content
    if ( $content.length === 0 ) {
        $content = $body;
    }

    // Internal Helper
    $.expr[':'].internal = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
        // Prepare
        var
            $this = $(obj),
            url = $this.attr('href')||'',
            isInternalLink;

        // Check link
        isInternalLink = url.substring(0,rootUrl.length) === rootUrl || url.indexOf(':') === -1;

        // Ignore or Keep
        return isInternalLink;
    };

    // HTML Helper
    var documentHtml = function(html){
        // Prepare
        var result = String(html)
            .replace(/<\!DOCTYPE[^>]*>/i, '')
            .replace(/<(html|head|body|title|meta|script)([\s\>])/gi,'<div class="document-$1"$2')
            .replace(/<\/(html|head|body|title|meta|script)\>/gi,'</div>')
        ;

        // Return
        return $.trim(result);
    };

    // Ajaxify Helper
    $.fn.ajaxify = function(){
        // Prepare
        var $this = $(this);

        // Ajaxify
        $this.find('a:internal:not(.no-ajaxy)').click(function(event){
            // Prepare
            var
                $this = $(this),
                url = $this.attr('href'),
                title = $this.attr('title')||null;

            // Continue as normal for cmd clicks etc
            if ( event.which == 2 || event.metaKey ) { return true; }

            // Ajaxify this link
            History.pushState(null,title,url);
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

        // Chain
        return $this;
    };

    // Ajaxify our Internal Links
    $body.ajaxify();

    // Hook into State Changes
    $window.bind('statechange',function(){
        // Prepare Variables
        var
            State = History.getState(),
            url = State.url,
            relativeUrl = url.replace(rootUrl,'');

        // Set Loading
        $body.addClass('loading');

        // Start Fade Out
        // Animating to opacity to 0 still keeps the element's height intact
        // Which prevents that annoying pop bang issue when loading in new content
        $content.animate({opacity:0},800);

        // Ajax Request the Traditional Page
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                // Prepare
                var
                    $data = $(documentHtml(data)),
                    $dataBody = $data.find('.document-body:first'),
                    $dataContent = $dataBody.find(contentSelector).filter(':first'),
                    $menuChildren, contentHtml, $scripts;

                // Fetch the scripts
                $scripts = $dataContent.find('.document-script');
                if ( $scripts.length ) {
                    $scripts.detach();
                }

                // Fetch the content
                contentHtml = $dataContent.html()||$data.html();
                if ( !contentHtml ) {
                    document.location.href = url;
                    return false;
                }

                // Update the menu
                $menuChildren = $menu.find(menuChildrenSelector);
                $menuChildren.filter(activeSelector).removeClass(activeClass);
                $menuChildren = $menuChildren.has('a[href^="'+relativeUrl+'"],a[href^="/'+relativeUrl+'"],a[href^="'+url+'"]');
                if ( $menuChildren.length === 1 ) { $menuChildren.addClass(activeClass); }

                // Update the content
                $content.stop(true,true);
                $content.html(contentHtml).ajaxify().css('opacity',100).show(); /* you could fade in here if you'd like */

                // Update the title
                document.title = $data.find('.document-title:first').text();
                try {
                    document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = document.title.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;').replace(' & ',' &amp; ');
                }
                catch ( Exception ) { }

                // Add the scripts
                $scripts.each(function(){
                    var $script = $(this), scriptText = $script.text(), scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
                    if ( $script.attr('src') ) {
                        if ( !$script[0].async ) { scriptNode.async = false; }
                        scriptNode.src = $script.attr('src');
                    }
                        scriptNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptText));
                    contentNode.appendChild(scriptNode);
                });

                // Complete the change
                if ( $body.ScrollTo||false ) { $body.ScrollTo(scrollOptions); } /* http://balupton.com/projects/jquery-scrollto */
                $body.removeClass('loading');
                $window.trigger(completedEventName);

                // Inform Google Analytics of the change
                if ( typeof window._gaq !== 'undefined' ) {
                    window._gaq.push(['_trackPageview', relativeUrl]);
                }

                // Inform ReInvigorate of a state change
                if ( typeof window.reinvigorate !== 'undefined' && typeof window.reinvigorate.ajax_track !== 'undefined' ) {
                    reinvigorate.ajax_track(url);
                    // ^ we use the full url here as that is what reinvigorate supports
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                document.location.href = url;
                return false;
            }
        }); // end ajax

    }); // end onStateChange

}); // end onDomLoad

})(window); // end closure
```

Let me explain it a little bit better.

The website has a music player that plays music while you are visiting the website, so clearly the music is not ment to stop whenever you click on a link.

This script works perfectly but it does refresh the whole page (using ajax) AND it is refreshing the music player.

There also is another script that comes with this one for changing the url and title ...

Thanks in advance, Greets

Answer (score 0):

use the statechangecomplete event.

```
$(window).on('statechangecomplete', function(e, eventInfo){
//your code
})
```